# Не возвращается значение по ключу

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Решаю сейчас задачу для своего первого тестового проектика на рельсах, нужно сделать транслитерацию вводимого текста (например для формирования ЧПУ). Мне уже несколько раз скинули ссылки на настройку транслитерации с использованием готовых библиотек, однако для успешного освоения рельсов хочу освоить руби и транслитерацию желаю написать сам.
Итак, что мы имеем:
введённая строка, хэш с парами символ=>символ_после_транслитерации, молодые неопытные руки.
Первая проблема возникла на этапе downcase, пришлось писать не title.downcase а title.mb_chars.downcase, так как первый вариант не работал.
Далее, полученную строку разбиваю в массив и посимвольно формирую новую, заменяя текущее значение элемента массива на соответствующее из хэша.
Так вот, после применения mb_chars значение из хэша не возвращается, хотя пробовал даже создавать новый хэш, ключи которого формируются с использованием mb_chars, но всё тщетно, в чём моя вина при реализации (помимо отказа от готовых решений)

Здесь результат
http://pastebin.com/5vDy2J7K
Стоит заметить, что без использования mb_chars всё работало прекрасно, за исключением downcase (и как следствие отсутствие транслитерированных символов в верхнем регистре, так как верхнего регистра в хэше нет)

Заранее спасибо всем откликнувшимся.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вашего кода вообще не понял. Надеюсь, вы поймёте

```
"ЧТОЗАВЕСЁЛАЯзадча".mb_chars.downcase.chars.map {|c| transliteration[c] || ''}.join # => "chtozavesyolayazadcha"
```

Comment: Я тоже свой код плохо пока понимаю=)
Оказывается всё намного проще, а я по привычке из колледжа (там основы плюсов изучали) вручную дохрена лишнего фигачу=(
Большое спасибо)

Comment: @Deadik: Почитайте why's Poingnant Guide to Ruby (http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/) и всё поймёте.

Read the following aloud to yourself: 
    ['toast', 'cheese', 'wine'].each { |food| print food.capitalize  }

Comment: Ссылочка ведёт на notfound, но думаю что и так найду

Comment: Скобочку в конце url'а просто уберите.